# stop spark dataframe distributing to cluster - it needs to stay on driver

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, rdd

we have a workload that computes on spark cluster workers (cpu intensive).
The results are pulled back to the driver which has a large memory allocation to collect the results via RDD .collect()
Results are then further processed resulting in a pandas dataframe (pre-existing package logic, can't change).

That pandas dataframe then needs to be stored into databricks.
This is done via converting the pandas dataframe to spark dataframe after which .saveAsTable is called.

The problem: for a table with 900 columns, and only 50k rows, the conversion of the pandas dataframe to the spark dataframe takes 5 minutes.
I have googled this heavily, and the only information I can glean is that the conversion of the pandas dataframe to the spark dataframe causes an automatic partitioning of the data accross the cluster workers. I believe this might be why it is so slow, as the step to actually save the data from the spark dataframe to a databricks table only takes 10 seconds (in comparison).

Is there a way to force spark dataframe to not distribute/parallelize ? I want it to simply stay on the driver, so I can use it's nice write api for saving into databricks.

I have tried setting: spark.default.parallelism 1 to force it not to distribute the workload, yet it still seems to send the data to a worker, rather than staying on the driver (i could be wrong but that is what it looks like from the logs).

There are methods on spark dataframe to repartition() & coalesce(), but these apply once the dataframe is already created rather than before, which defeats the purpose of trying to save time when creating the spark dataframe in the first place.

Any thoughts?

```
delta_frame.write \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("delta.columnMapping.mode", "name") \
    .option("mergeSchema", "true" if merge_schema else "false") \
    .option("path", target_path) \
    .partitionBy(partition_cols) \
    .saveAsTable(full_table_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

it appears the premise of my question was somewhat wrong.

the whole concept of pyspark dataframe is directly linked to pyspark RDDs (resilient distributed datasets). So you can't have one without the other.
pyspark dataframe IS going to create an RDD whether you like it or not which means it is doing a bunch of overhead to move data into the JVM.

Unless the cluster has arrow enabled (it is disabled by default), then the performance of converting a pandas dataframe to a pyspark dataframe is extremely poor. In my instance, 400+ seconds, vs 25 seconds when arrow is enabled on the cluster.
Thus the answer for me was adding this to the cluster config:

spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enable true

could also be done within a notebook:

## Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")

The whole idea of only using the driver to covert pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe is poor, as the conversion process itself can make use of the cpu on the cluster workers to speed up the conversion to spark dataframe utilizing arrow.